# Mouseup detection not working as expected after drag with line draw

Tags: vuejs2, konvajs

I am currently using the following library: https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/

The project is basically to carry out the following test, which is to connect the texts with the images by drawing a line

[image]

For which I have the following code:

```
<v-stage 
            :config="configKonva" 
            ref="stage" 
            @mousemove="moviendoLinea" 
            @mouseup="eliminarLinea"
            class="configkonva"
            style="position: fixed !important;"
        >
            <v-layer ref="layer">
                <v-image 
                 :config="{ image: image_mono, draggable: false, width: 70, height: 70, x: 130, y: 0}"
                 @mouseup="trazarLineaMono"
                 ref="imgMono"
                ></v-image>
                <v-line :config="configLine"></v-line>
                <v-line :config="configLineTxtMono"></v-line>
                <v-line :config="configLineTxtMoto"></v-line>
                <v-line :config="configLineTxtPaleta"></v-line>
                <v-line :config="configLineTxtPelota"></v-line>
                <v-image
                 :config="{image: img_text_mono, x: 125, y: 170}"
                 ref="monoRef" 
                 @mousedown="iniciarLineaMono"
                >
                </v-image>
            </v-layer>
        </v-stage>

iniciarLineaMono(){
                let vm = this;
                console.log("CREANDO LINEA MONO");
                vm.ir_generando_linea_mono = true;
                const mousePos = this.$refs.stage.getStage().getPointerPosition();
                vm.configLineTxtMono = new Konva.Arrow({
                    points: [mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mousePos.x, mousePos.y],
                    pointerLength: 10,
                    pointerWidth: 10,
                    fill: 'blue',
                    stroke: 'blue',
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    draggable: false
                });
            },

    trazarLineaMano(event){
                    let vm = this;
                    console.log("TRAZANDO LINEA MANO");
                    vm.$refs.imgMano.getNode().off("mouseup");
                    vm.mano_seleccionado = true; //La linea ha llegado a tocar la imagen 'mano' por tal razon es true, ha sido seleccionada.
                    if(vm.ir_generando_linea) {
                        console.log("HAND TEXT IS CONNECTED WITH HAND PICTURE, CORRECT
");
                        vm.ir_generando_linea = false;
                        vm.$refs.manoRef.getNode().off("mousedown");
                        vm.puntuacion.mano = 1;
                    }
                    else if(vm.ir_generando_linea_mono){
                        console.log("MONKEY TEXT IS CONNECTING WITH HAND PICTURE
");
                        vm.ir_generando_linea_mono = false;
                        vm.$refs.monoRef.getNode().off("mousedown");
                    }
                    else if(vm.ir_generando_linea_moto){
                        console.log("MOTORCYCLE TEXT IS CONNECTING WITH HAND PICTURE
");
                        vm.ir_generando_linea_moto = false;
                        vm.$refs.motoRef.getNode().off("mousedown");
                    }
    },
```

The problem is that while I am drawing the line and being on the image and releasing the click does not execute the @mouseup event, therefore it does not enter the method 'traceLineaMono', now if I am alone on the image and click and then I release click this way the @mouseup event is already executed.

The strange thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. Beforehand thank you very much

NEW INFORMATION:

What happens is that releasing the click is done on the line, how can I do so that such a situation does not happen?

Simulating arrow:
The arrow is exactly on the line

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your code but I wonder if this is an issue with the construction of the canvas at the point in time when you release the mouse. In some cases the redraw of the line will have completed and the object under the mouse at the mouseup time will be the line - in other cases it not.

Comment: Can you make online demo of your issue with codesanbox? Probably it doesn't trigger mouseup on the image, because at the moment you have a line under mouse position. So the line triggers `mouseup`.

Comment: In fact, the problem is that the mouse is on the line, then it performs the test using the @mouseup event on the line and the event is actually done. How can I correct such a situation, that is, the mouse is not on the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to clarify, the code connects the mousedown point to the current mouse pointer position using a arrow object as the UI element. The issue is that the mouse-up event is being fired on the arrow object and not the mono image so the logic regarding the connection check is never fired.

The answer is to stop the line listening for events.  See [this example](https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Listen_for_Events.html) in the konva docs. The basic approach to disable event listening in pure JS is object.listening(false). You may have to adapt slightly for Vue.

When you start using drawn objects for UI feedback, finding the mouse events to be hijacked by the drawn object is a common tripping point for folks new to it - you are walking a well-trodden path!